# Make Picturebox Transparent in Visual Basics 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am a beginners so please answer me in detail so that i will be able to do it. 
I am making a simple application in visual basics 2010.

I have two picture boxes in my form one is for background and another one is the object which will move... i have to make the second picture box transparent. 
I have a png image to insert on that box which is of transparent background.
Please help me ..

Comment: There are several ways to do this but your question is too poorly documented to give a recommendation.  If this is some kind of animation then the likeliest chance for success is to not use 2 pbs but just use the Paint event to draw the image.

Comment: yes it is an animation but. I don't know about the paint event. I created background with picturebox because background will also has to move. then i insert the object with picture box but it is not transparent.

Comment: Well, you got something to focus on then.  Very well covered in any introductory book or decent tutorial on Winforms programming, there is no point in repeating this here.

Answer (score 0):

Here, the important thing is the parent. You can load a transparent picture to the  PictureBox (Note: You can load a BMP file, as well). You can define any color as transparent. See the picture.

In this project:

The parent of Panel1 is Form1.

The parent of PictureBox1 is Panel1.

The parent of PictureBox2 is PictureBox1.

The parent of PictureBox3 is Form1.
[image: Sample Project]

If you make PictureBox1 transparent, then you will see it is only transparent for Panel1 (which is PictureBox1's parent). In other words, you can see the Panel1's Background under the transparent color.

If you make PictureBox3 transparent, then you will see it is only transparent for Form1 (which is PictureBox3's parent). In other words, you can see the Form1's Background under the transparent color.

That's why, as much as I understand, in your project the parent of PictureBox2 should be PictureBox1. You can load (or draw) a picture for PictureBox1. Then you can load your animation picture to PictureBox2 which has a transparent color.

Please see the code below:

```
...
    PictureBox2.BackColor = Color.Transparent
    PictureBox2.Size = New Size(1042, 1474)
    PictureBox2.Location = New Point(55, 0)
    Dim bmp As Bitmap
    bmp = (System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("empty.bmp"))
    bmp.MakeTransparent(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255))
    PictureBox2.Image = bmp
...
```

Hope, it helps.